# I'm trying to post an employee along with his schedule to this trial site

Tags: c#, api, post

I'm trying to use API's in order to

1. Login to site with my credentials
2. To register this employee in this company(x employee works for y company), and
3. Add his working schedule

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private class WTOS
        {
            public List<WTO> WTO { get; set; }
        }
        private class WTO
        {
            public string f_aa_pararthmatos { get; set; }
            public string f_rel_protocol { get; set; }
            public string f_rel_date { get; set; }
            public string f_comments { get; set; }
            public string f_from_date { get; set; }
            public string f_to_date { get; set; }
            public Ergazomenoi Ergazomenoi { get; set; }
        }
        private class Ergazomenoi
        {
            public List<ErgazomenosWTO> ErgazomenoiWTO { get; set; }
            public Ergazomenoi()
            {
                ErgazomenoiWTO = new List<ErgazomenosWTO>();
            }
        }
        private class ErgazomenosWTO
        {
            public string f_afm { get; set; }
            public string f_eponymo { get; set; }
            public string f_onoma { get; set; }
            public string f_date { get; set; }
            public ErgazomenosAnalytics ErgazomenosAnalytics { get; set; }


        }
        private class ErgazomenosAnalytics
        {
            public List<ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics> ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics { get; set; }
            public ErgazomenosAnalytics()
            {
                ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics = new List<ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics>();
            }
        }

        private class ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics
        {
            public string f_type { get; set; }
            public string f_from { get; set; }
            public string f_to { get; set; }
            public ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics() { }
        }
        private class Ergazomenos
        {
            public string f_afm { get; set; }
            public string f_eponymo { get; set; }
            public string f_onoma { get; set; }
            public string f_date { get; set; }
            public string f_working_time_digital_organization { get; set; }
            public string f_full_employment_hours { get; set; }
            public string f_week_days { get; set; }
            public string f_euelikto_wrario_minutes { get; set; }
            public string f_working_card { get; set; }
            public string f_dialeimma_minutes { get; set; }
            public string f_dialeimma_entos_wrariou { get; set; }
            public Ergazomenos() { }
        }
        private class Login
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string UserType { get; set; }

        }

        private class AccessToken
        {
            public string accessToken { get; set; }
            public int AccessTokenExpired { get; set; }
            public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
            public string RefreshTokenExpired { get; set; }
            public AccessToken() { }
        }

        private class Authenticate
        {
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string Usertype { get; set; }
        }
        private class Cards
        {
            public CardsClass CardsCards { get; set; }
        }

        private class CardsClass
        {
            public List<Card> Card { get; set; }
        }
        private class Card
        {
            public string f_afm_ergodoti { get; set; }
            public string f_aa { get; set; }
            public string f_comments { get; set; }
            public Details Details { get; set; }
        }
        
        private class Details
        {
            public List<CardDetail> CardDetails { get; set; }
        }

        private class CardDetail
        {
            public string f_afm { get; set; }
            public string f_eponymo { get; set; }
            public string f_onoma { get; set; }
            public string f_type { get; set; }
            public DateTime f_reference_date { get; set; }
            public DateTime f_date { get; set; }
            public string f_aitiologia { get; set; }
        }

        public class Submission
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public string Protocol { get; set; }
            public string SubmitDate { get; set; }
        }

        private class SubmissionsCode
        {

            public String Id { get; set; }
            public String Code { get; set; }
            public String Description { get; set; }
        }

        private static String GetAccessToken()
        {

            String sURL = "httpS://trialeservices.yeka.gr/WebServicesAPI/api/Authentication";

            Authenticate Auth = new Authenticate();
            Auth.Username = "ika0000ba5f";
            Auth.Password = "031263";
            Auth.Usertype = "01";
            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Auth);

            byte[] send = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.ContentLength = send.Length;
            req.Accept = "application/json";

            Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
            sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
            sout.Flush();
            sout.Close();
            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

            Stream ReceiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
            string responseFromServer = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            dynamic JsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
            var AccessToken = JsonResponse.accessToken.ToString();

            return AccessToken;
        }

        private static String GetSubmissionCode(String token, String Description)
        {
            String Code = "";
            String sURL = "httpS://trialeservices.yeka.gr/WebServicesAPI/api/Lookup/Submissions";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token;
            req.Accept = "application/json";

            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

            Stream ReceiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
            string responseFromServer = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            dynamic JsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
            //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            var SubmissionsCodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubmissionsCode>>(responseFromServer);
            foreach (SubmissionsCode sCode in SubmissionsCodes)
            {
                String sCodeDescription = sCode.Description;
                if (sCodeDescription == Description)
                {
                    Code = sCode.Code;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return (Code);
        }

        private static Submission CreateNewSubmission(String token, String Code) {
            Submission nSubmission = new Submission();
            /*
            CardDetail nCardDetail = new CardDetail();
            nCardDetail.f_afm = "012345678";
            nCardDetail.f_eponymo = "ΚΑΠΟΙΟΣ";
            nCardDetail.f_onoma = "ΛΑΜΠΡΟΣ";
            nCardDetail.f_type = "0";
            nCardDetail.f_reference_date = DateTime.Now.Date;
            nCardDetail.f_date = DateTime.Now;
            nCardDetail.f_aitiologia = "aitiologia";

            List<CardDetail> CardDetail = new List<CardDetail>();
            CardDetail.Add(nCardDetail);
            Details nDetails = new Details();
            nDetails.CardDetails = CardDetail;

            Card nCard = new Card();
            nCard.f_afm_ergodoti = "012345678";
            nCard.f_aa = "0";
            nCard.f_comments = "test from REST API";
            nCard.Details = nDetails;

            
            List<Card> Card = new List<Card>();
            Card.Add(nCard);
            CardsClass nCardsClass = new CardsClass();
            nCardsClass.Card = Card;
            var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Card);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
            var jsonString2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nCard);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonString2);
            */
            
            String sURL = "https://trialeservices.yeka.gr/WebServicesAPI/api/Documents/" + Code;
          
            String postdata = "";
            postdata += "{";
            postdata += "\"Cards\": {";
            postdata += "\"Card\": [";
            postdata += "{";
            postdata += "\"f_afm_ergodoti\": \"094084006\",";
            postdata += "\"f_aa\": \"0\",";
            postdata += "\"f_comments\": \"test\",";
            postdata += "\"Details\": {";

            postdata += "\"CardDetails\": [";
            postdata += "{ \"f_afm\": \"161262385\",\"f_eponymo\": \"Λαζίδης\",\"f_onoma\": \"Αλέξανδρος\",\"f_type\": \"1\",\"f_reference_date\":\"2022-12-08T12:45:00\",\"f_date\": \"2022-12-08T12:45:00\",\"f_aitiologia\": \"\"}";

            postdata += "]";

            postdata += "}";
            postdata += "}";

            postdata += "]";

            postdata += "}";
            postdata += "}";
            Console.WriteLine(postdata);
            
            byte[] send = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);


            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + token;
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            req.ContentLength = send.Length;
            req.Accept = "application/json";

            Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
            sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
            sout.Flush();
            sout.Close();
            
            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

            /*
            Stream ReceiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
            string responseFromServer = readStream.ReadToEnd();

            dynamic JsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
            Console.WriteLine(JsonResponse);
            */
            return (nSubmission);
        }
        public static void SendOrario(string token)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var wtos = new WTOS();
            var wto = new WTO();
            var erganawto = new ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics();
            erganawto.f_from = "10:00";
            erganawto.f_to = "18:00";
            erganawto.f_type = "ΕΡΓ";
            var ergazomenosanalytics = new ErgazomenosAnalytics();
            ergazomenosanalytics.ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics.Add(erganawto);


            //var res = client.PostAsJsonAsync<WTOS>(url, login).Result;
        }

      
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Get Token
            String token = GetAccessToken();

            if (token!="") {
                //Get Submissions Code for new employee
                String Description = "Δήλωση έναρξης/λήξης εργασίας εργαζομένων";
                String Code = GetSubmissionCode(token, Description);
                Submission nSubmission = new Submission();
                if (Code!="") {

                    nSubmission = CreateNewSubmission(token, Code);

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Code = " + Code);
                //Console.WriteLine("SubmissionId = " + nSubmission.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("==============================");
                

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

the json object the sites wants for the employee has the following schema :

```
{
"WTOS": {
"WTO": 

{
"f_aa_pararthmatos": "0",
"f_rel_protocol": "",
"f_rel_date": "",
"f_comments": "",
"f_from_date": "13/12/2022",
"f_to_date": "13/12/2022",
"Ergazomenoi": {
"ErgazomenoiWTO": 

{
"f_afm": "161262385",
"f_eponymo": "ΛΑΖΙΔΗΣ",
"f_onoma": "ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΣ",
"f_date": "13/12/2022",
"ErgazomenosAnalytics": {
"ErgazomenosWTOAnalytics":

{
"f_type": "ΕΡΓ",
"f_from": "10:00",
"f_to": "18:30"
}


}
}


}
}


}
```

and for his working schedule :

```
{
"WorkingStatusChanges": {
"WorkingStatusChange": 
{
"f_aa_pararthmatos": "0",
"f_rel_protocol": "",
"f_rel_date": "",
"f_comments": "",
"Ergazomenoi": {
"Ergazomenos":   
{
"f_afm": "161262385",
"f_eponymo": "ΛΑΖΙΔΗΣ",
"f_onoma": "ΑΛΕΞΑΝΔΡΟΣ",
"f_date": "12/12/2022",
"f_working_time_digital_organization": "1",
"f_full_employment_hours": "40,0",
"f_week_days": "5",
"f_euelikto_wrario_minutes": "0",
"f_working_card": "0",
"f_dialeimma_minutes": "30",
"f_dialeimma_entos_wrariou": "0"
},

}
}
  
}
}
```

Code brokes, I got an error 400 at WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
I also commented some lines such "CardDetail" because I dont want some classes for now

Comment: I've suggested an edit to put the code fences in the right place, but I haven't touched the JSON, you may want to make an edit to indent the JSON correctly for readability. 400 means "bad request", which may well mean that your request isn't quite the right shape for the schema expected by the API. Try debugging the program and comparing the request you're actually sending with the required schema. Debugging may also reveal some detail in the response body to indicate what's wrong with the request, although that depends on the API.

Comment: Figured out that if I place the correct day(today's date) is working. But I'm not sure if it works actually, it would be great if you could run it and give me your thoughts.